# Adding hint (like in a search box) to SWT one-line Text

Tags: java, text, textbox, swt

I want to create an installer, which downloads files from a URL which is going to be a default value if the `Text` is blank, and the "hint" will be

> Insert your specific URL

And I'm wondering how to add the hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [`Text`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html). Especially the method `setMessage(String)`:

> Sets the widget message. The message text is displayed as a hint for the user, indicating the purpose of the field.